# Htaccess Redirect 301 for urls with question mark

Tags: redirect

I need to make a 301 redirect, for about 8000 Urls, the last number of the url is random

Url origin:
https://example.com/fr/recherche?limit=1&ajaxSearch=1&id_lang=3&q=730852109438

Destination:
https://example.com/fr/

I have tried many things but I can not make it work.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried ? Maybe one of the things you've tried would work with some minor modifications.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)